# Tensorflow : ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid. It should be a callable with no arguments and `shape` should be fully defined

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to work with a TensorFlow model and I am getting this error :

> ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid. It should be a
>   callable with no arguments and the shape should not be provided or an
>   instance of `tf.keras.initializers.*' and`shape` should be fully
>   defined.

The code looks like this :

```
      sentences             = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,None], name='sentences')
      self.targets          = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='labels'  )

      word_embedding            = tf.get_variable(name='word_embedding_',
                                     shape=[vocab_size, word_embedding_dim],
                                     dtype=tf.float32,
                                     initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())




    # lookup and sequence count ----------------------------------------------------------->>
    # embedding lookup
    embedding_lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding, sentences)

    # ignore padding during sequence unfolding in lstm
    sequence_leng = tf.count_nonzero(sentences,axis=-1)



    # sequence learning network ------------------------------------------------------------->>

    #bilstm model
    with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
        fr_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = rnn_units)
        dropout_fr = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(fr_cell, output_keep_prob = 1. - keep_prob)

    with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
        bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = rnn_units)
        dropout_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(bw_cell, output_keep_prob = 1. - keep_prob)

    with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
        model,last_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(dropout_fr,
                                                           dropout_bw,
                                                           inputs=embedding_lookup,
                                                           sequence_length=sequence_leng,
                                                           dtype=tf.float32)


    logits = tf.concat([last_state[0].c,last_state[1].c],axis=-1)






    # dense layer --------------------------------------------------------------------->>

    # dense layer with xavier weights
    fc_layer = tf.get_variable(name='fully_connected',
                               shape=[2*rnn_units, self.targets.shape[1]],
                               dtype=tf.float32,
                               initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    # bias 
    bias    = tf.get_variable(name='bias',
                               shape=[self.targets.shape[1]],
                               dtype=tf.float32,
                               initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    #final output 
    self.x_ = tf.add(tf.matmul(logits,fc_layer),bias)




    #optimization and loss calculation ---------------------------------->>
```

Comment: You are using a `tf.placeholder` `self.targets` that has shape `[None, None]` to initialize your `fc_layer` and `bias`. Variable shape needs to be fully defined (i.e not contain `None`s

Comment: @thushv89 post an answer with the issue description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following lines,

```
fc_layer = tf.get_variable(name='fully_connected',
                           shape=[2*rnn_units, self.targets.shape[1]],
                           dtype=tf.float32,
                           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

# bias 
bias = tf.get_variable(name='bias',
                       shape=[self.targets.shape[1]],
                       dtype=tf.float32,
                       initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

If you look at `self.targets.shape[1]` that is equal to `None`. TensorFlow will not allow you to generate `tf.Variable` objects without their full shape defined. This means that none of their dimensions can be `None`. Thus, you got the error.

So doing the following changes should fix the issue. I am just giving a value to the last dimension of the `targets` placeholder.

```
n_units = <some value>

sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,None], name='sentences')
self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_units], name='labels'  )

word_embedding = tf.get_variable(name='word_embedding_',
                                     shape=[vocab_size, word_embedding_dim],
                                     dtype=tf.float32,
                                     initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

# ... this part stays the same

# dense layer --------------------------------------------------------------------->>

# dense layer with xavier weights
fc_layer = tf.get_variable(name='fully_connected',
                            shape=[2*rnn_units, self.targets.shape[1]],
                            dtype=tf.float32,
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

# bias 
bias = tf.get_variable(name='bias',
                            shape=[self.targets.shape[1]],
                            dtype=tf.float32,
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

#final output 
self.x_= tf.add(tf.matmul(logits,fc_layer),bias)
```